# Setting page state on load (during a GET request)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Currently, my navigation bar uses AJAX to load new pages and `window.pushState()` to update the URL if the AJAX is successful.

I've realised I need to push the page state on get requests so back/forward events will have a state for my `popstate` listener to handle.

Should I simply inject the following script into the HTML my server responds with?

```
<script>
    window.pushState(state, null, null);
</script>
```

Or is there a way to push the state with the response (to GET)?

EDIT: An use case would be, user enters domain.com/ -> then follows a link in the navbar (which AJAX loads new content), currently if the user hits the back button nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close to the solution. You can change the url using `window.history.pushState`.

```
// Call this function when you get response with url  
function processAjax(response, url){
     // Get whatever you want from response and push it in state
     document.title = response.pageTitle; 
     // You can push other information here also
     window.history.pushState({"pageTitle": response.pageTitle}, response.pageTitle, url);
}
```

For setting the state on load, just call `window.history.pushState` without third parameter which is url.

Note that, using pushState will change the url without reloading the page, which is what I think you want according to my understanding.

After this you can listen to `window.onpopstate` event to detect navigation changes:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
     if (e.state) {
        var pageTitle = e.state.pageTitle;
        // Or alternatively get other information and do whatever you want with it
     }
}
```

Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: Ah yes my AJAX already handles that, what I want is a way to give the window.history a state when a user just accesses the URL, e.g. domain.com/gallery

Comment: I have edited the answer, basically you can call pushState without third parameter that is url and it will set the state for you. I have tried this in console and can confirm that it works.

Comment: I know this :) thus the script I have in my question, I wanted to know if there was a better way to handle this as that feels a little hacky.

Comment: Since, history object is made for this specific purpose, I won't say it is hacky. All of the routers for major framework use history object to manipulate states, so it should be the way to go.

Comment: I don't think manipulating the history object using is hacky. Rather injecting a script into HTML to perform a task I thought would have been manageable from PHP.

Comment: Just have that in your html template in which you output your PHP output. So that whenever page loads that html template is always there. For new pages that are opened by clicking navbar, it would be taken care of by processAjax function.